# BufferedReader not reading file (Android)

Tags: java, android, file-io, dictionary, bufferedreader

I am having a problem reading files with bufferedReader... I am trying to read in a dictionary file where every word is on a newline. It works for one file I have, but when I tried adding a larger wordlist file the enable wordlist and then on the first read: 'while ((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null) '  it cause an exception with no description... Please help!

```
try
    {
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.enable1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String currentLine=null;

        while ((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            dictionaryList.add(currentLine);       
        }
        br.close();                 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //error here
    }
```

*Looks like there is a file size limit of 1048576 bytes... otherwise it crashes.

Comment: The exception gets stopped by the `catch` block that you have. You just aren't printing anything inside of the `catch` block. Try adding `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: thanks, but I figured out the problem the new wordlists where over 1048576 bytes so it was causing the io exception... I'm going to split the wordlist up into files by word length... should make it load faster for what I am doing!

Answer (score 0):

So I like I said in the edit the new wordlist was over 1048576 bytes and was causing an IO exception without any error... (i had a string set to e.Message() in the catch put the message was null)

What I did was divide the wordlist into separate files based on word size (btw there are 26 different files! message me if you want them)

then depending on the size of the word I have I load the specific wordlist where all of the files are in the format enable# (# is the word size). If anyone wants to know I am doing that like this:

```
int wordListID=0;    
String wordList="enable"+goodText.length();

try {
Class res = R.raw.class;
        Field field = res.getField(wordList);
        wordListID= field.getInt(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //something
    }
```

i then send that specific wordListID to:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(wordListID);
```

and know I have a small enough file which actually helps my performance too!

*This is my first application so I may not be doing things the correct way... just trying to get the hang of things